# Find unique values and then retrieve all associated values

Tags: r, duplicates, aggregate

So i am trying to convert a file with over a million rows which looks like below for example:

```
A 1

B 7

A 15

B 2

D 25

A 3

C 12

B 9
```

But with a lot more rows. I want to convert this data frame into the format below:

```
A 1 15 3

B 7 2 9

C 12

D 25
```

I've used this so far:

```
subset(rawdata, !duplicated(rawdata$Col1))
```

where rawdata is the dataset. But this just gives the first corresponding value associated with each unique column.

Comment: Try `df1 <- unique(df);split(df1$col2, df1$col1)`

Comment: The problem is that there cannot be such a data frame. You could maybe use `tapply(DF$v, DF$id, FUN = unique)` or something.

Comment: `aggregate(V2~V1, df, function(x) paste(x, sep=' '))`